Why isn't my method called? .NET MAUI and DevExpress AgendaView
I'm trying to call a method by clicking on an item of my list.
using DevExpress.Maui.Scheduler; (for the appointments classes)
The list comes from an AppointmentItemCollection in my ViewModel.
This collection is populated with AppointmentItem
The appointments are displaying like they should but I can't find a way to make the "Tap" event call a method in my xaml.cs
I first tried the same as DevExpres:
        <dxsch:AgendaView
            x:Name="agendaView"
            MaxDate="{Binding maxDate}"
            MinDate="{Binding minDate}"
            ShowEmptyDays="False"
            Start="{Binding Start}"
            Tap="agendaView_Tap">

and here is the method's signature:
void agendaView_Tap(object sender, SchedulerGestureEventArgs e)
Simple isn't it?
And when typing the method's name, the event manager recognized it.
So the method should be called right?
I even tried adding an AgendaView.GestureRecognizers (like I did for a DataGridView), but same, nothing is working.
Did I miss something?
for the doc:AgendaView.Tap Event
I'm thinking about doing a dyi Agenda with a DataGridView, it is easier to bind methods with it, but it might be uglier.

how are you determining that it isn't called?  Are you using the debugger?  Or is it just not behaving as expected?

Yeah I used the debugger, and nothing happens
edit: Is there any other way to see what's going on?
